# Can I use an array as a parameter in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am solving Project Euler Problem #3. I think I've done the first half, but I'm not sure how to find the largest number in my array of factors. Is there a way to use an array as a parameter in a function?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <ctime>

    bool isPrime(int);

    bool isPrime(int x){
        if(x==2){
            return true;
        }
        if(x%2==0){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            if(x%i==0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }



    int prime_factors(int x){ 
        int j = 0;
        int arry[900];
        for(int i = 0; i<x;i++){
            if(isPrime(i)==true){
                if(x%i==0){
                    arry[j]=i;
                    j++;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to pass your array around. Most consistent with you current code would be:

```
int largest_prime_index(int* array, int length)
{
   if (length < 1)
   {
       return -1;
   }

   int largest_index = 0;

   for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] > array[largest_index])
      {
         largest_index = i;
      }
   }

   return largest_index;
}
```

Note, if you were using your `arry` variable, you would use `j` for `length`, not `900`.